# Problem with merging dict items while iterating on list of dicts

Tags: python-3.x

I'm iterating over a list of dicts looking like this:

```
sold_products = [{"quantity": "15", "variantUuid": "66de6c1d-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4", "name": "bananas "}, 
{"quantity": "12", "variantUuid": "66de6c05-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4", "name": "apples "}, 
{"quantity": "4", "variantUuid": "66de6c0f-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4", "name": "cherries"}, 
{"quantity": "1", "variantUuid": "66de6c0f-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4", "name": "cherries"}, 
{"quantity": "6", "variantUuid": "66de6c1d-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4",  "name": "bananas "}]
```

and wrote two functions to merge items in the list so that items with the same variantUuid would see their quantities summed up.

```
def merge_sales(sold_products):

    temp = []

    for product in sold_products:
        uuid = product['variantUuid']

        if uuid not in temp:
            temp.append(uuid)
            product['seen'] = True

        else:
            quantity_to_add = int(product['quantity'])
            update_sales(sold_products, uuid, quantity_to_add)
            sold_products.remove(product)

    return sold_products


def update_sales(sold_products, uuid, quantity_to_add):
    for product in sold_products:
        if product['variantUuid'] == uuid and product.get('seen') == True:
            updated_qty = int(product['quantity']) + quantity_to_add
            product['quantity'] = updated_qty


merged_products = merge_sales(sold_products)

for key in merged_products:
    print(key['variantUuid'], key['name'])
```

output:

```
66de6c1d-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4 bananas 
66de6c05-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4 apples 
66de6c0f-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4 cherries
66de6c1d-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4 bananas
```

I can see twice the same item, and quantities were not added.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am unable to replicate this based on your current. code. I have copy and pasted what you gave and for me temp shows `['66de6c1c-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4', '77uec81c-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4']`

Comment: Aside from the extra indentation prior to your for loop, I can't replicate the problem you have described running this either. Please give us the exact minimal code you have ran that has given you this result.

Comment: Note that a ``set`` is in general more efficient than a ``list`` to test whether a value has been seen previously.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I didn't identify the problem correctly and updated both the Title and question to reflect the actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the root issue is that you're overcomplicating things:

```
def merge_sales(products):
    merged = dict()
    for item in products:
        qty = int(item["quantity"])
        k = item["variantUuid"]
        if k in merged:
            merged[k]["quantity"] += qty
        else:
            merged[k] = item.copy() # so we don't change the original
            merged[k]["quantity"] = qty # so we do have an int
    return list(merged.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you remove elements in `sold_products` list while you are iterating it. When you remove an element the following elements goes one position back to the begining and your loop skips the next element. I suggest to remove these elements with a new loop in reverse order. Something like this should work:

```
sold_products = [
{"quantity": "15", "variantUuid": "66de6c1d-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4", "name": "bananas "}, 
{"quantity": "12", "variantUuid": "66de6c05-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4", "name": "apples "}, 
{"quantity": "4", "variantUuid": "66de6c0f-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4", "name": "cherries"}, 
{"quantity": "1", "variantUuid": "66de6c0f-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4", "name": "cherries"}, 
{"quantity": "6", "variantUuid": "66de6c1d-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4",  "name": "bananas "}
]

def merge_sales(sold_products):

    temp = []

    for product in sold_products:
        uuid = product['variantUuid']

        if uuid not in temp:
            temp.append(uuid)
            product['seen'] = True

        else:
            quantity_to_add = int(product['quantity'])
            update_sales(sold_products, uuid, quantity_to_add)

            # This line caused the problem
            # sold_products.remove(product)

    # Now elements will be removed
    for i in range(len(sold_products)-1, 0, -1):
        if not sold_products[i].get('seen'):
            sold_products.pop(i)

    return sold_products


def update_sales(sold_products, uuid, quantity_to_add):
    for product in sold_products:
        if product['variantUuid'] == uuid and product.get('seen') == True:
            updated_qty = int(product['quantity']) + quantity_to_add
            product['quantity'] = updated_qty


merged_products = merge_sales(sold_products)

for key in merged_products:
    print(key['variantUuid'], key['name'], key['quantity'])

# output:
# 66de6c1d-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4 bananas  21
# 66de6c05-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4 apples  12
# 66de6c0f-9ce4-11e9-af25-0b218a4387e4 cherries 5
```